# Prestashop : Change product price from front

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I want to create a product that we can change his price from the front .
There's a way to do this please?
This product will appear just in cart tpl so we can add him to the list by Ajax.

Comment: Please i really need your help .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fast way is add attributes (combinations) to product which will change the price. Then in front office the user change attribute for example "+10$" (this is a label) in this product.